# jQuery Tablesorter not sorting table on page load

Tags: tablesorter

I'm having issues on my WordPress page getting tablesorter to sort the data when the page initially loads.  When the page initially loads it sorts the table by post date.  Any way I can get it sorted by date_signed in descending order when the page loads initially?  I can click the sort button on the table after the page has loaded and it sorts just fine, so its working, its just ignoring the initial sort function.   I'm not a strong coder, so I appreciate the help.  I'm working with existing code.

Thanks!

```
<?php /* Template Name: All Court Orders */ ?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

        <?php
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'header' ); ?>


<?php // Get all amendments
    $posts = get_posts(array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'court_order',
        'meta_key' => 'date_signed',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'order'   => 'DESC'

    )); ?>


    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">

        <div class="table-responsive" id="tblOpinions">
            <table class="table table-striped tablesorter" id="myTable">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Order Name</th>
                    <th>Date Signed</th>
                    <th>Effective Date</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
               <?php foreach ($posts as $post) { ?>

                    <?php
                        $file = get_field('file_upload');
                        $dateSigned = get_field('date_signed', false, false);
                        $dateSigned = new DateTime($dateSigned);
                        $dateEffective = get_field('effective_date', false, false);
                        $dateEffective = new DateTime($dateEffective);
                        $name = get_the_title();
                    ?>

                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="<?php echo $file['url']; ?>" target="_blank" class="pdf"><?php the_title(); ?></a></td>
                        <td><?php echo $dateSigned->format('m/d/Y');  ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $dateEffective->format('m/d/Y') ?></td>
                    </tr>

                <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
   </div>
   </div> 

        <?php endwhile; // End of the loop. ?>
    </main><!-- #main -->
</div><!-- #primary -->

<?php
get_footer(); ?>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $("#myTable").tablesorter( {
            sortList: [[1,1]]
        });
    } 
); 
</script>
```

Comment: Hmm, using `sortList: [[1,1]]` should work. Are you seeing any errors in the devTools console? And it looks like you're already sorting the table using php, maybe just leave out the `sortList` option?